# Does Eurolines provide a map (list or other resource) with origin / destination cities (or locations)?

Tags: online-resources, europe, buses

I am assessing my needs to do some travel and one of the options I am considering is bus. I went to the eurolines website but they don't seem to have an overall europe origin/destination table to see where they travel from/to.

Each country website has its own information and it's not even coherent sometimes (There are bus connections missing in some that exist in others).

Does anyone know if such resource exists and where?

Comment: I was also looking for sth like map, the best what i found is http://www.eurolines.fr/en/destinations_1/international-network/ unfortunately nothing better :(

Comment: Can you indicate which countries are you moving around?

Comment: @fedorqui - mainly France, Belgium, Luxembourg, Netherlands and Germany.

Comment: You can always try http://www.eurolines.fr/en/contacts_1/contact-online/ .

Answer (score 8):

Surprinsingly enough, different national version of the Eurolines websites offer different type of information :

- the [timetable page on the British site](http://www.eurolines.co.uk/timetables), on the [German site](http://www.eurolines.de/Fahrplaene.861.0.html) and on the [Spanish site](http://www.eurolines.es/es/rutas-eurolines/horarios-y-tarifas/) provide you a bunch of timetable you can download which might look like what you are looking for. Please note that on the website from a given country, I only found the routes from/to that country.
- the [timetable page on the French site](http://www.eurolines.fr/en/destinations_1/timetables/) and on the [Belgian site](https://www.eurolines.be/fr/destinations_2/reseau_eurolines/) seem to only work through explicit requests *(It's also possible that the information is somewhere on the website and I just didn't look properly on the site but if a native French speaker doesn't find it, it might be even harder for tourists ;-))*

If after trying all the different versions you don't find what you are looking for, it might be worth using the contact form to suggest they should add it. I have little hope it would do anything but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 5):

I think the inconsistency with the various Eurolines websites stems from the very fact that each country is served from a local company (National Express in England, Touring in Germany, etc.)

Alternatively but quite similarly to the answer above (or below :)) you could use a google search query with the following pattern:

```
eurolines <country> 2014 filetype:pdf
```

to bring up all relevant leaflets.